# Publishing as Pre-Compiled ASP.net-MVC Website with VWD Express Edition

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, publishing, vwdexpress

Is there a way to pre-compile websites with VWD Express ?

Can I use ASP.NET Merge tool or similar utility ? and is there any limitation to options (can I choose whatever options like in VS Pro edition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% about VWD but do you have post build options within IDE (under the Build Events of the web application properties)

Even without you could run following from the command line

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler -v / -f -u -p 
"$(ProjectDir)\" "$(SolutionDir)PrecompiledWeb\$(ConfigurationName)"
```

Comment: @dove: thanks for your answer, but I need more clarification about how to achieve same results of pre-compilation with Pro version (Build views, Enable updating or compile all to dll) ...etc Thanks again

Comment: @ahmed look at aspnet_compiler /?  and you'll details of the flags there, e.g. -u means updatable.  Also you might want to look at web deployment projects  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with anything generated by VS Express, but you should be able to build and deploy the website using a custom MSBuild script no matter where it came from. Something like:

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\MyProject.csproj"
         Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"
         Properties="WebProjectOutputDir=$(MyTargetDir);OutDir=$(WebProjectOutputDir)\;Configuration=Release" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make it easier by creating a custom external tool, here is how I did it:
http://blog.larmib.com/2012/how-to-compile-visual-web-developer-2010-express/

To make things easier I created a Settings file precompile.vssetting. Enjoy, please +1 my blog if you find my post helpful.